# Set Control Property While Looping Through Controls

Tags: vba, ms-access, userform

This VBA code below can be used to loop through all controls on a form, but how do I set any of the control's properties using the Control Name c.name?

```
 Dim c As Control
 For Each c In Me.Controls
     If TypeName(c) = "TextBox" Then
         MsgBox "Control Name= " & c.name & " Control Value = " & c.Value

        'I'm looking for this Part:  c.name  .BackColor = 255

     End If
 Next
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use the name property? Why not just `c.Backcolor = 255`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eh, just set the property?

```
 Dim c As Control
 For Each c In Me.Controls
     If TypeName(c) = "TextBox" Then
         c.BackColor = 255
     End If
 Next
```

Intellisense won't work since you're using the general `Control` and not the specific `TextBox` interface, but it'll run just fine.

Comment: Yep. I answered my own question a minute after I posted this one. I'm rusty in VBA - haven't looked at a VBA project since before my hair went grey.

Answer (score 3):

It's best to first define which controls you're looking to change and then include that in your For cycle.

```
Dim c As Control
Dim txt As TextBox

For Each c In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf c Is TextBox Then
        Set txt = c
        txt.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    End If
Next c
```

Comment: Thanks for this. In the intended application I'm reusing one form to handle 12 different operations and the code needs to look through every control and match to an array of controls that are used for a specific operation and position them, and if not used, hide them. BackColor was just used an example.

Answer (score 0):

To set the `BackColor` of a `Textbox` you would access it directly:`TextBox1.BackColor = 255`.

The way you are attempting this is through the `Name` property of the `TextBox`, which simply returns a string.

Essentially what you were doing is `TextBox1.Name.BackColor = 255`, which would cause an error:

> compile error: invalid qualifier.

So the correct way to do it would look like:

```
Dim c As Control
For Each c In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(c) = "TextBox" Then
        c.BackColor = 255
    End If
Next
```

If you want to use intellisense then you could set a reference to a temporary variable.

```
Dim c As Control
For Each c In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(c) = "TextBox" Then
        Dim TempTextbox As Access.TextBox
        Set TempTextbox = c
        TempTextbox.BackColor = 255
    End If
Next
```

Here is [Microsofts Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.textbox) on the Textbox Object (Access). You can use this as a reference for its different methods and properties.

Comment: Thank you for the intellisense tip. I've never thought of doing that.

Answer (score -1):

It's been too long since I dabbled in VBA. 
The (obvious) correct answer to my question is:
c.BackColor = 255